# Facebook Graph API - Peak Live Viewers' metric?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

From within the facebook creator studio I can look at performance details for my video. Once of the metrics that I can see from here is 'Peak Live Viewers`.

I'm looking though the Facebook Graph API video_insights documentation and I can't find a reference to this 'Peak Live Viewers' metric.

So is the 'Peak Live Viewers' number available though the Graph API?
If so how?

Comment: Someone has surely used this before. Is this something that is available on their site but not via the API?

Comment: I am still amazed that I have no responses to this. Seems like this would be a metric that many would be interested in.